# Python api request to gitlab unexpectedly returns empty result

Tags: python, api, github, pycharm, gitlab

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/ahmed_sh/projects")
print(response.status_code)  # 200
print(response.text)  # []
print(response.json()) # []
```

I'm trying to get a list of my GitLab repo projects using python API, but the outputs are nothing! Although, when I use the browser, I got a non-empty response. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You might need to pass some sort of authentication header. Also, don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Sorry, for the images of code, I used my access token but it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you don't have any public projects in your user namespace. If you want to see your private projects in your namespace, you'll need to authenticate with the API by passing a personal access token in the PRIVATE-TOKEN header.

Note, this also won't show projects you work on in other namespaces.

```py
headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'Your API key here!'}
resp = requests.get('https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/ahmed_sh/projects', headers=headers)
print(resp.json())
```

Comment: @Ahmedsherif glad this worked. If this answers your question, consider accepting it. Welcome to StackOverflow :-)